# How to fix assembly binding error in .Net core for multiple versions of same nuget package

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget

I have a .Net Core 2.1 App. The 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App' package here uses the '2.1.0' version of 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection' package.
I want to download another third party package which requires the '3.1.0' version of the same 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection' package. I have tried to fix this by directly downloading the '3.1.0' version of the package. After doing this, the application builds correctly. But when I try to start the app, I get an error. The event viewer has the following error

> Exception Info: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Is there a way to fix this error?

Comment: There is a screen called "Manage Nuget Packages for solution". From that screen you can check the versions of all projects in your solution and modify them. This issue is probably about conflicts around Package versions.

Comment: @ycansener - Yep. I modified the package version there. The AspNetCore.App package is now scoped the the new version of 'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection' package. But when i try to run the application , i am getting the above error.

Comment: You need to check packages.config file of your project. There should be some incorrect information in it. And also check every config file in your project to be sure that version information of all packages are how they supposed to be.